# Cannot pass a valid communicator from fortran to c/c++

Tags: c++, fortran, mpi, interop, openmpi

After passing MPI communicator from Fortran to C/C++ and upon checking the size communicator resulted in the following error message:

> An error occurred in MPI_Comm_size on communicator...MPI_COMM_WORLD
>   ...MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator

Although the communicator on C/C++ side is not `MPI_COMM_NULL`, looks like it is not valid either. Below are the code that produced the error message.

**C++**

```
extern "C" 
{
    MPI_Comm* f_MPI_Comm_f2c(MPI_Fint f_handle)
    {
        MPI_Comm* comm;
        comm = (MPI_Comm*)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Comm));
        *comm = MPI_Comm_f2c(f_handle);
        assert(*comm != MPI_COMM_NULL);

        int size;
        MPI_Comm_size(*comm, &size);
        std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;

        return comm;
    }
}
```

**Fortran module**

```
module mymodule

use mpi
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding, only: c_ptr, c_null_ptr

implicit none
private

interface

    function f_MPI_Comm_f2c(comm) result(optr) bind(C, name="f_MPI_Comm_f2c")
        import c_ptr
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: comm
        type(c_ptr) :: optr
    end function f_MPI_Comm_f2c        

end interface

type(c_ptr), save :: ccomm = c_null_ptr

public :: CreateCcomm

CONTAINS

    subroutine CreateCcomm(com)
        !type(c_ptr) :: ccomm
        integer, intent(in) :: com
        ccomm = f_MPI_Comm_f2c(com)
    end subroutine CreateCcomm

end module mymodule
```

**Fortran driver**

```
program main

use mpi
use mymodule, only : CreateCcomm
IMPLICIT NONE
integer error

call MPI_Init(error)
call CreateCcomm(MPI_COMM_WORLD)
call MPI_Finalize (error)

end
```

Comment: You're sure that the Fortran and C++ codes use the same size of integer for communicator identifiers ?

Comment: I am not sure but I tried to define `MPI_Comm comm` on stack instead of defining `MPI_Comm* comm` and allocating. However, I got the same error.

Comment: your `C` function argument should be `MPI_Fint *`. You can try to keep it as a `MPI_Fint` but use the `value` modifier in the Fortran interface (I never tried, and I do not guarantee it will work).

Comment: Yes, making `MPI_Fint*` solved the problem. Please also post answers in addition to commenting in this and my previous question.